# Convert Flash art to OpenGL-ready vector format?

Tags: iphone, flash, opengl, flash-cs4

Say I have some 2D artwork in Flash CS4 format .FLAs, and I'd like to put it into an iPhone game that uses OpenGL ES, keeping it in vector format. An OpenGL-ready format could just be a list of vertex positions and colors for a triangle strip.

Is there a converter available that can do that easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend converting the swfs to .svg format, Either in Illustrator, or with this [online tool](http://www.eprg.org/~sgp/swf2svg.html). I actually used a [small java console app](http://www.mgatelabs.com/wiki/Flash_Exploit_Tutorials#FECL) to automate this part for what I had to do recently, it worked pretty well.

Once that's done, you can use Qt to do the rendering bit for you as [commented on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027179/displaying-svg-in-opengl-without-intermediate-raster).

Answer (score 3):

You could port [gameswf](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html) to iPhone, it supports most SWF tags, it loads and renders in OpenGL. It's coded in C++ so it's easy to embed it into your iPhone application. Be warned that's it's usable but it has its limits.

Answer (score 2):

[Claus Wahlers](http://wahlers.com.br/claus/blog/hacking-swf-1-shapes-in-flash/)'s project looks pretty cool, check out: https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/shape-export-to-objective-c

[image: ca logo swf]

[image: ca logo app]

Answer (score 0):

You could use smokescreen to convert the flash to html5, and then use the stock HTML viewer found In interface builder. Just my 2 cents.