# OpenGL or Rasterizer for playing SVG

Tags: opengl-es, svg, rasterizing

I am planning to write a SVG player. To have the animation run at 20 frames/second I want to generate images at that rate and throw it at the screen.
Now to do this what would be a better option, whether to convert the SVG into a OPenGL sequence or just rasterize the SVG into a image buffer directly,
I am no expert on OpenGL, neither am on Image Processing but can learn either of them whichever is relevant to the problem.

Comment: You should clarify whether you want to animate static SVGs via OpenGL somehow or if you want play animated SVG containing SMIL elements. I'm not aware of anything that can load/implement the SMIL bits out of the box. For static SVGs, the question linked by genpfault below has plenty of answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [good solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027179/displaying-svg-in-opengl-without-intermediate-raster).