# iOs draw an intereactive map

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

I need to draw an interactive map for an iOs application. For example it can be the map of the US showing the states. It will need to show all the states  in different colors ( I'll get this from a delegate `colorForStateNo`: ) It will need to allow the user to select a state by touching it, when the color will change, and a "stick out" effect should be shown, maybe even a symbol animated to appear over the selected state. Also the color of some states will need to change depending on external events. This color change will mean an animation like a circle starting in the middle of the state and progressing towards the edges changing the color from the current one to the one inside the circle.
Can this be done ,easily in core-graphics? Or is it only possible with Open GL ES? What is the easiest way to do this? I have worked with core graphics and it doesn't seem to handle animation very well, I just redraw the entire screen when something needed to move... Also how could I use an external image to draw the map? Setting up a lot of drawLineToPoint seems like , a lot of work to draw only one state let alone the whole map ...

Comment: to allow interactions with users, using images are probably not an option. It is more advised to render your map's interactive part using rendering library, such as OpenGL ES, Cocos2D, etc.

Comment: And could I use some sort of ... game engine? ... so I don't hard code all the lines in the map...

Comment: you should work on your logic yourself. Even with "game engine", they don't know how your map works .

Comment: I have the logic ... it's the "how to display that" part that bugs me

Answer (score 0):

You could create the map using vector graphics and then have that converted to OpenGL calls.
[Displaying SVG in OpenGL without intermediate raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027179/displaying-svg-in-opengl-without-intermediate-raster)

EDIT: The link applies to C++, but you may be able to find a similar solution.

Comment: hmm . I'll look into it ... might be something